# Am not able to load tidyverse in R 4.0.5 any leads?

Tags: r, tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
```

I just updated my **R** to version **4.0.5** but when I try  to load tidyverse I get this error. Anyone with an idea?

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’: .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'tidyverse', details: call: base::nchar(wide_chars$test, type = "width") error: lazy-load database 'C:/Users/motieno/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/cli/R/sysdata.rdb' is corrupt

Comment: Try removing and re-installing tidyverse.
`remove.packages("tidyverse");install.packages("tidyverse")`

Comment: Try this: Close all. and Restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more general method to update R version and allready installed packages accordingly is to use the `installr` package:

```
if(!require("installr")) install.packages('installr')
library("installr")
updateR() # this will open dialog boxes to take you through the steps.
# OR use:
# updateR(TRUE) # this will use common defaults and will be the safest/fastest option
```

Comment: Thank you @pietrodito. Very useful indeed. I will try the ```updateR(TRUE)``` function in my next update.

Comment: No need to thank me, just accept my answer if you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

This just solves it thanks to @mhovid

```
remove.packages("tidyverse");install.packages("tidyverse")
```